# Represent counts of Yes / No answers as a decimal in a report

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, iif

I have a report that looks like this:

```
Query Name           Attempts        Successes      Failures    SuccessProportion
First Query             1               0               1               0/1
Second Query            1               0               1               0/1
Third Query             2               1               1               1/2
Fourth Query            1               1               0               1/1
Fifth Query             1               0               1               0/1
Sixth Query             1               0               1               0/1
```

this is my code that creates the report:

```
            l_strsql = "SELECT Query_Name, " +
                 " Attempts, " +
                 " Successes, " +
                 " Failures, " +
                 " CAST([Successes] AS NVARCHAR(10)) + ' / ' + CAST([Attempts] AS NVARCHAR(10))  AS Proportion " + 
                 " FROM ( " +
          "SELECT generate_query AS Query_Name, " +
                 " sum(case when RecNum is NOT NULL then 1 else 0 end) AS Attempts, " +
                 " sum(case when export_TIR = 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end) AS Successes, " +
                 " sum(case when export_TIR = 'No' then 1 else 0 end) AS Failures " +
                 " FROM tbl_TPF " +
                 " WHERE export_type = 'Excel' " +
                 " GROUP BY generate_query " +
                 " ) Q ";
```

How can I get the SuccessProportion to show as a decimal with 2 places after the decimal? - is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   " CAST([Successes] AS NVARCHAR(10)) + ' / ' + CAST([Attempts] AS NVARCHAR(10))  AS Proportion
```

That line is setting it to a varchar, which is the 1/2 format you are seeing.

```
             " CAST([Successes] AS numeric(8,2))  /  CAST([Attempts] AS numeric(8,2))  AS Proportion
```

that should give a numeric value as a success/attempts.  There is no 0 handling (attempts = 0 means a div by 0 error), but I suspect from your query, that won't happen

edit - one final cast to get to the final format you want:

```
" cast(CAST([Successes] AS numeric(8,2))  /  CAST([Attempts] AS numeric(8,2))  as numeric(8,2))"
```

Comment: the answer now looks like 0.66666666666 -- It doesn't seem to convert the format of (8,2)

Comment: Ah yes, I forget how precision in division works.  Cast the final result to numeric as well then?   edit in answer